# MySQL Latest Timestamp + Other Field with Group By

Tags: mysql, group-by, timestamp

I have a table that stores events and timestamps as they relate to tasks being performed. A "report" task is a collection of "tests," each with its own set of events and associated timestamps.

The structure is as follows:

```
reportID
testID
eventDateTime
eventType
```

Each eventType is something like "Start", "Pause", "Finish", etc. What I'm trying to do is write a query that will tell me the last action taken on a given reportID/testID combination and its timestamp.

My preliminary query is:

```
SELECT reportID, MAX(eventDateTime), eventType
FROM testtracker_event
GROUP BY reportID, testID
```

The result is very close to what I want, and I'm getting the latest eventDateTime (which I want), but it's returning the first eventType (as opposed to the eventType associated with the most recent timestamp.)

I realize *similar* questions have been asked, but I've searched and searched and this seems much simpler than any similar questions I've found. I want to believe this is possible without a subquery or join but I'm getting the idea based on answers to similar questions with more complicated logic that it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's going wrong is, since 'eventType' is not part of the GROUP BY clause, the SELECT clause does not know which 'eventType' from the group to select in response to the query. Hence, by default it usually selects the first one. Most other RDBMS systems would not allow you to select a field that is not specified in the GROUP BY clause without some aggregate function being applied to it (MAX, SUM, etc).

You might want to try something like this:

```
SELECT reportID, eventDateTime, eventType
 FROM testtracker_event t
 WHERE t.eventDateTime = (
   SELECT MAX(eventDateTime) FROM testtracker_event inner_t
   WHERE t.reportID = inner_t.reportID AND t.testID = inner_t.testID
   GROUP BY reportID, testID
)
```

I've used a correlated subquery to get the latest timestamp for each (reportID, testID) combination, and use that as the comparison in the outer query.

Hope this works.

Comment: Threw a GROUP BY reportID, testID after the closing parenthesis and it works like a charm. Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh, also put a "testID" in the initial SELECT. Thanks again.